# Xcode 6.0.1 crashing issue material inspector

Tags: crash, xcode6, collada, scenekit

I recently installed xcode to play with the Scenekit for game and 3D apps. I can navigate myself around just fine and play with the assets in a .dae file, the problem is (only) when I click on the Material Inspector when selecting the material, xcode or the whole computer crashes. Any ideas on fix?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You should [file a radar](http://bugreport.apple.com) about it and attach all the relevant crash logs. You might also want to try a different, simpler .dae file to see if you can narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I reported it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple:
"Engineering has determined that your bug report is a duplicate of another issue and will be closed.

The open or closed status of the original bug report your issue was duplicated to appears in the yellow "Duplicate of XXXXXXXX" section of the bug reporter user interface.

Duplicate of 18304513 (Open)"

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that this a known OpenGL driver bug on Mavericks, If you have access to Yosemite it should work fine.